# Layout mismatch between development & build in Gatsby

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and source my data from Airtable plugin. I also use gatsby-image for lazy loading and stuff. The problem is that the render is correct in gatsby develop, But when I gatsby build, the second item of the airtable data is taking the first spot with broken UI. It only gets fixed when I click another gatsby link and click back to the homepage.

I think it's caused by gatsby-image but I just don't understand what's wrong with it. Here's the deployed preview: https://5f97de1908aca50007e75d94--hey-gamer.netlify.app/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often happens when you're doing something 'illegal' with your HTML structure, i.e `<div>` as direct descendant of `<ul>`, `<button>` inside `<button>`, etc.

In your case, you're having nested `<a>`. When you have this html:

```html
<a href="#foo">Hi!
  <a href="#bar">Hello!</a>
</a>
```

The browser will move the inner link out so that both links are under the same parent:

```html
<a href="#foo">Hi!</a>
<a href="#bar">Hello!</a>
```

If you open your site without javascript, this is what you'll see:
[image]

The browser has done you a 'favor' and fixed your nested anchors for you!

---

#### Why it works with React

Now, this happens when a browser parses your html. What happens if you manually nest the anchor tags with javascript?

```html
<a id="one" href="#foo">Hi!</a>
<a id="two" href="#bar">Hello!</a>

<script>
  let $a1 = document.getElementById('one')
  let $a2 = document.getElementById('two')

  $a1.appendChild($a2)
</script>
```

It doesn't care, so you can actually have nested anchors... if you fiddle with the DOM after it has loaded.

This is why your Gatsby-prerendered page looks kinda normal. When React showed up, it was smart enough to reshape the DOM for you, but it still made a mistake: your 2nd anchor was appended to the wrong node.

When you came into this page from another link, Gatsby didn't pre-render the HTML for you, so React just happily produced the structure that the browser deemed illegal.

#### What to do

You should fix your structure, don't wrap the card with an anchor tag. If your card **must** be clickable, <s>you could make it clickable manually instead of using an anchor tag & deal with the a11y issues, or</s> use CSS to make the anchor tags appear to be nested (with absolute positioning for example) eventhough they're siblings.

Here's a CSSTrick article on this issue: [Nested Links](https://css-tricks.com/nested-links/)